# How do I save corrupt Minecraft files? (Windows 10 Edition)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In one of my previous questions I asked about losing a bunch of stuff like my house in my Minecraft world due to what I thought was a chunk error. As it turns out, I have about 10 ‘lost’ files in my Minecraft world and I am desperate to find out how to recover them. I’ve tried using software to recover them and they all say it’s successful but when I try to put them back into the world folder it’s still the same - they just disappear when I log on. Any solutions?

Comment: When you say "*they just disappear when I log on*", are you saying that you can clearly see the structures, briefly, when your world loads, or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Ah sorry, I should've specified. I mean the files I replace just disappear and the world is still the same as before. I keep my file explorer open to check for changes as I log in and play. As my world loads in the 'lost' files I attempted to recover disappear from the list and go back into the 'lost' folder.

Answer (score 1):

Verify you have enough storage space and that you have the ability to write to the location.

If you ever ran the game as the Administrator, you indirectly made some of the files unable to be saved as your normal user account, and making the process of properly recovering said files more of a hassle.

On the other hand, if you manually messed with the game's stored files, you likely may have caused other issues.
When adding a world or Add-on (resource pack / shader, behavior pack / Bedrock Scripting API thing, etc.), you should only *Import* them by double-clicking on the `.mcworld` / `.mcpack` / `.mcaddon` / `.mctemplate` file.
If it opened in another program, you (or someone else using the computer) changed something. Right-click the file -> "Open With" -> "Choose another app" and then find "Minecraft" and select it before clicking "OK" (if *Minecraft: Java Edition* is also installed, make sure to ***NOT*** select that one).